# arcgis hotkey work outside of map

Tags: arcgis

make map on page:

```
function initMap() {
        return require([
                            "esri/map",
                            "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
                            "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
                            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
                            "esri/graphic",
                            "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
                            "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
                            "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
                            "esri/symbols/TextSymbol",
                            "esri/symbols/Font",
                            "esri/geometry/Circle",
                            "esri/geometry/Polygon",
                            "esri/geometry/Point",
                            "esri/SpatialReference",
                            "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
                            "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
                            "dojo/request/script",
                            "dojo/_base/array",
                            "dojo/promise/all", "dojo/Deferred", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/json",
                            "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
                            "esri/symbols/CartographicLineSymbol",
                            "esri/geometry/Polyline",
                            "esri/Color",
                            "dojo/dom-construct",
                            "dojox/charting/Chart",
                            "dojo/domReady!"
        ],
        function (  Map, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, FeatureLayer, Graphic, SimpleFillSymbol,
                    SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, TextSymbol, Font, Circle, Polygon, Point, SpatialReference,
                    webMercatorUtils, GraphicsLayer, script, array, all, Deferred, dom, on, JSON, PictureMarkerSymbol, CartographicLineSymbol, Polyline, Color, domConstruct, Chart) {  // function parameters must be in the same order as requires

            map = new Map("map", {
                center: [99.999, 99.999],
                zoom: 12,
            });
            var mapServiceURL = "http://server.com/arcgis2/rest/services/Common/BASEMAP_BIPD/MapServer";
                map.addLayer(new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(mapServiceURL));
           });
    }
```

it shows correctly. With map make same textbox on page. Sometime then user write in textbox any number using numeric pad at right of keyboard (near numlock), number is not write, but map is start keyboard navigate. Numlock in numeric state. 
It's not every time. then user click any other textboxes and return to this to continie write number - it writes correctly.

How repair it or disable arcgis hotkey?

*(на всякий:
подключаю карту на страницу, но при наборе чисел на доп клавиатуре в стороннем поле на странице фокус стоит на этом поле, но двигается карта, вместо ввода цифр (нумлок в правильном положении). Лечится сменой фокуса по разным полям несколько раз. Как-то можно отключить хоткеи, или починить такое нездоровое поведение?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to disable the map keyboard navigation when user focus in the textbox. Then, when focus out, enable it again. To accomplish this, use these functions found in [the docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html):

```
map.enableKeyboardNavigation();
map.disableKeyboardNavigation();
map.isKeyboardNavigation;
```